# IBoutlet is nil in my custom table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

//custom cell in one swift file

```
import UIKit

class CardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var elapsedTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var todo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startAndStop: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progress: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!

}
```

//custom Table view controller in another swift file

```
import UIKit

class CardFeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(CardTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cardCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 3
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: CardTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardTableViewCell
        cell.todo.text = "study"
        return cell
    }
```

[running the app triggers a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChfD9.png)

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShxZJ.png)

I don't know why all the properties in the my table cell is nil, when I run the app.

Comment: If you did not use xib, you should remove the line register from view did load, otherwise, you should use register cell nib for identifier
tableView.register(UINib...", forCellReuseIdentifier: CardTableViewCell.self)

Comment: em~, can you give me more details? I still don't why it should be like this? T_T

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> There are two variants to register, but both take a parameter called
>   **forCellReuseIdentifier**, which is a **string** that lets you **register**
>   different kinds of **table view cells**. For example, you might have a
>   reuse **identifier "DefaultCell"**, another one called **"Heading cell"**,
>   another one **"CellWithTextField"**, and so on. Re-using different cells
>   this way helps save system resources.
>
> If you want to use **register()** with a Swift class, you provide a **table
>   view cell class** as its first parameter. **This is useful if your cell is
>   defined entirely in code**. As an example, this uses the default
>   UITableViewCell class:

```
tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DefaultCell")
```

**You can then dequeue that cell like this:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DefaultCell")!
    return cell
}
```

> The other option is to use **register()** with an **Interface Builder nib
>   file**. **Nibs contain the class name to use along with their design, so
>   this method is more common**. Here's an example

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "yourNib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CellFromNib")
```

> But if you're using storyboards you will find it easier to create
>   prototype cells and give them a reuse identifier directly inside
>   Interface Builder.**So no need to register programmatically**.

Remove this line form `viewDidLoad`

```
tableView.register(CardTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cardCell).
```

Comment: I forget to connect the tableView outlets T_T

Comment: Mark the answer correct then because  it is not required when you are using storyboard.

Comment: but why in my way of registering will trigger a error ??? thanks for your help : -)

Comment: does only create a cell programmatically need to register that cell in code???@Tushar Sharma

Comment: @user4274847 yes.When you create table view with coding then you need to perform that register() step.As you can not give identifier in storyboard then.

Comment: thank you. and setting the "custom row height" in size inspector doesn't change the row height when I run the app, why ??? T_T @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @user4274847 first can you mark the answer correct if it was helpful.

Comment: @user4274847 are you using heightforrow method as well ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I wish I could, but I just don't have enough reputation to make your answer correct. @tushar Sharma

Comment: @user4274847 this is nothing related to reputation you can still do it.Just click on check mark

Comment: I see ~ @Tushar Sharma

Comment: "`But if you're using storyboards you will find it easier to create prototype cells and give them a reuse identifier directly inside Interface Builder. So no need to register programmatically.`". This is what I missed. Thanks!